# py2exe and 3rd party modules deployment

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, pywin

My python app loads other py or pyc files and execute them. I am shipping my app as executable (bundled as single or multiple files - does not matter). I want my app to support adaptive installation. For example: If I ship my app (bundled exe) including `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`, and later on, I want the user to install only `ModuleC` instead of the entire app. I am looking for the following options:

1. If I can ship `ModuleA.pyc` and `ModuleB.pyc` separately in the
   distribution rather than zipped in `myApp.exe`? I am assuming that user can install
   M`oduleC.pyc` by copying it to the same directory of other Modules. And, it will work
   for a `new_script.py` (via import `ModuleC`) which will be executed by `myApp.exe`.
2. If first is not possible, then what is the other way of shipping `ModuleC` rather
   than the whole `myApp.exe` bundle.

Awesome people, please suggest that how can I do it or is there any better approach of doing it.

Thanks a lot in advance.